# How to perform CRUD operation in node js with client api

Tags: node.js, rest

This below code gives output for GET user list but i want 
 it also to delete and post some element in test.json file memory :

delete data using name i.e localhost:8080/alpha
and when we add user using post in api client it should save in test.json as new element with existing element

So can anyone edit the following code for me :)

test.json

```
[
    {
        "name":"alpha",
        "password": "123"
    },
    {
        "name":"beta",
        "password": "321"
    }
] 

 //main.js

 var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var fs = require("fs");

    app.get('/listUsers', function (req, res) {
        fs.readFile(__dirname + "/" + "test.json", 'utf8', function (err, data) {
            if (err) { return console.log(err); }
            console.log("All users :" + data);
            res.end(data);
        });
    });

    app.delete('/:name', function (req, res) {

    });

    app.post('/postUser', function (req, res) {

    });

    var server = app.listen(3000, function () {

        var host = server.address().address
        var port = server.address().port

        console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)

    })
```

Comment: You must use `res.send` not `res.end`. For the `delete` you must read the file then change the data by removing the element you want and then write that data again to the file and for `post` you simply need a writeFile function.

Comment: As i am beginner can you edit the code for me :)